# How to expose child control property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I wrote a user control `MyCustomToggleButton` which encapsulate a toggle button. I'd like to show or hide a grid based on the `IsChecked` property of the toggle button. I added a dependency property `Expanded` (I woudn't mind reusing the `IsChecked` property again) which I control via the `Checked` event of the toggle button.

```
<controls:CustomToggleButton x:Name="MyCustomToggleButton">

<Grid Visibility="{Binding Expanded, ElementName=MyCustomToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=False}"
```

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Expanded), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(false));


public bool Expanded
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(ExpandedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ExpandedProperty, value);
    }
}

public MyCustomToggleButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();
     
    // ToggleButton is the name of the toggle button defined in XAML.
    ToggleButton.Checked += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Expanded = true;
    };
    ToggleButton.Unchecked += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Expanded = false;
    };
}
```

How can I bind the `Expanded` property of the user control to the `IChecked` property of the toggle button?

Comment: I am not the most skilled WPF guy, but I have been working with WPF for five years now and I have created thousands of controls and not single custom one. I am sure you can do anything just using templates. There are four levels of creating custom looks and all are possible within XAMl, not a single line of C# is involved. That is how it should be.
No need to complicate things beyond necessity

Comment: Why don't yout bind ToggleButton.IsChecked property with Expanded property using RelativeSource which specifies Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can I bind the Expanded property of the user control to the IChecked property of the toggle button?"*

First remove the event handling:

```cs
public CustomToggleButton()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

Next, bind the internal `ToggleButton` to the parent `CustomToggleButton.Extended` property:

```xml
<UserControl>
  <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Expanded}" />
</UserControl>
```

Creating a class named `CustomToggleButton` implies that you want to extend the behavior of the default `ToggleButton`. In this case you should literally *extend* `ToggleButton` and not wrap it:

```cs
class CustomToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
  // Optional: Override the default Style if desired
  // (in case you also want to change the default layout)
  static CustomToggleButton()
    => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomToggleButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomToggleButton)));
}
```

Then add a new default Style to the *Generic.xaml* where you can customize the layout (if this is desired)

```xml
<Style TargetType="CustomToggleButton">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="CustomToggleButton">

        ...
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```